# Term for Sets Equivalent Up To Closure

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Is there a nice name for the collection of sets that have the same closure?

I'm writing up some notes developing some tricks for visualizing topologies, and I kind of want a non-cumbersome way to refer to these.

There's a somewhat similar idea in non-standard analysis (points that are infinitesimally close together) and they call them "monads" or "halos". I dislike the former because it clashes with categorical terminology, but in the worst case, I might steal the latter.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. If I wanted to refer to one of the equivalence classes, I’d just talk about the dense subsets of some closed set. If I wanted to say that two sets were in the same class, I’d just say that their closures were equal. If I really felt a need for something shorter, I’d probably talk about closure-equivalent sets and closure classes.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! Closure classes is workable. Perhaps I unduly fixated on there being a special term. Though it does still feel like there's a niche for a term...